# Change the identical part of the name of many tables

Tags: mysql, sql

For example the AdventureWork database we have the following tables:

Person.BusinessEntity; Person.Address; Person.ContactType

How can I rename them to modify just the 'Person.' to something else or remove it?

Comment: You can use `information_schema.tables` to make alter table queries, that you can then run manually. There is no "ALTER TABLE SET name = REPLACE(name, stuff)" functionality in MySQL.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: You want to rename the schema (`person`) or the tables?